# Is it unsecure to cache a SecKeyRef of the public and private key in memory?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, encryption-asymmetric

I saw this [QA](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html) about encrypting and decrypting data using the iOS `Security.framework` where the code in the answer pointed to [Apple's Key Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html).

The codes in QA and Apple reference both query the public/private key before performing encryption/decryption.

In the code I'm going to write, I'm planning to hold the SecKeyRef in memory instead of querying it again every time I need to encrypt/decrypt. Is it safe to do that? Or there's a security reason why both examples query every time?

Comment: I think that, the query every time make sense because you can lose the reference to the SecKeyRef value (memory waring or other unexpected behaviours). So basically just to 100 % sure that you have the correct key you should do a query.